# How to get words from a online txt archive such as pastebin?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to coding/python and I'm trying to do a simple user checker with python but I don't know how to get the words from a www.site.com/mytextfile.txt or pastebin.com/raw/1111111

I will have multiple "users" which one in a new line

my code is something like this:

```
user = input('Write something')

     If user == this is where I want it to check the online txt:
         do something

     Else:
         do other something instead
```

The online txt will be like this:

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import requests # requests module of python (can be installed via pip)
    ...: url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/nkGg7bFy' # url of paste
    ...: r = requests.get(url) # response will be stored from url
    ...: content = r.text  # raw text from url
    ...: print(content) # prints content
    ...:
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain your answer