# How to get ip address from pastebin file in python

Tags: python-3.x, ip-address

I want to ask about how to take ip-address from pastebin file in python3, for example:

```
//normal code
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 443

//what i want
host = "https://pastebin.com/raw/ip-file"
port = 443
```

why i want this? because i want to change the ip-address randomly without touching the python script.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642698/how-to-get-words-from-a-online-txt-archive-such-as-pastebin

Comment: This is what i really want, thank you very much brother. :)